# MySQL Workbench sync keeps requesting the same changes

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench, and when I try to "synchronize" it with my remote database, it keeps detecting some changes to make.

Specifically, the most recurrent ones are:

- Dropping foreign keys and re-creating the same ones again
- Changing the collation

I was compliant and executed all the queries given to me (and added the semi-colon that they forgot). MySQL didn't complain and executed them.

However it didn't help, I can run it 20 times in a row, it will still ask the same useless changes.

Comment: Do you use the latest Workbench version?

Comment: Yes, 5.2.44 for OSX

Comment: What version and platform of MySQL Server?

Comment: 5.1.53 on OSX ..

Comment: I am still experiencing this today with MySQL Workbench 8.0.18... Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is a bug in MySQL Workbench. You should confirm this with some test database to see if you can replicate the issue and file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 (Mac), but I found a workaround...

I did the following:

1. export (forward engineer) sql script of my model
2. run the sql script on my local database
3. reverse engineer my local database
4. synchronize the resultant model with my production database

Now it only requests actual changes.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: wouldn't that completely mess up your ER diagram to your production database? I'm running into the same problem -- very annoying. And actually, after a few recent changes it wants to drop columns and re-add them when it generates the change script -- definitely not a good idea!

Comment: @RedRob Yeah... It is definitely not ideal. You would still have to carefully check the suggested "sync script"...